# Add SOAP header to dynamically invoke web service in c#

Tags: c#, web-services, web

How to add security SOAP header into dynamically invoked web service using c#?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask. Did you try _anything_ so far? Show your effort first. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] as a start..

Comment: I am using ServiceDescription to invoke my web service dynamically but i would like to add one string to SOAP header so that it can be extracted and authenticate the service call. I tried to add  using HttpWebRequest but it didnt work.                                                  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(srvuri);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", SecureTocken); Please advise.

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment. I mentioned HttpWebRequest and tried to add HTTP header instead of SOAP header.

Comment: I am using ServiceDescription to read WSDL and generating type and invloking the web service method.Please advise how can i add my custom string into SOAP header?